# Counting by index in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with 3 columns, `starring_id,` `actor_id` and `film_id`.

I need to count how many times each `actor_id` appears, then display two columns that show `actor_id` and how many times they appeared in the database.

I'm not sure how to do this in SQL `COUNT` when I want to tally how many times each appears, and show it in a table from my query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a simple `COUNT()` aggregate grouped by `actor_id`.  The official docs have a similar example. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select actor_id, count(*) as Appearances
from my_table
group by actor_id;
```

Comment: Works perfect, completely forgot about the group function. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, but I can't for another 4 minutes yet apparently